# Why is my custom call handler not called?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container, unity-interception

I'm trying to understand how to use call handlers with Unity. Here's the code I have so far:

```
void Main()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.AddNewExtension<Interception>()
             .Configure<Interception>()
             .AddPolicy("TestPolicy")
             .AddCallHandler(new TestCallHandler());
    container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>();
    var foo = container.Resolve<IFoo>();
    foo.Test();
}

interface IFoo
{
    void Test();
}

class Foo : IFoo
{
    public void Test()
    {
        "Foo.Test()".Dump();
    }
}

class TestCallHandler : ICallHandler
{
    public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextHandlerDelegate  getNext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[Interceptor] Calling {0}.{1}", input.MethodBase.DeclaringType.FullName, input.MethodBase.Name);
        return getNext()(input, getNext);
    }

    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

But `TestCallHandler.Invoke` is never called, it just calls `Foo.Test` directly. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register both the type and the handler and add an interceptor with a PolicyInjectionBehavior.

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.AddNewExtension<Interception>()
         .RegisterType<TesCallHandler>()
         .RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>(new Interceptor<TransparentProxyInterceptor>(),
             new InterceptionBehavior<PolicyInjectionBehavior>())
         .Configure<Interception>()
         .AddPolicy("TestPolicy")
         .AddCallHandler(new TestCallHandler());
var foo = container.Resolve<IFoo>();
foo.Test();
```

Comment: Thanks! It does indeed solve the problem. I thought it was possible to do it globally for all types.

Comment: MSDN document warns that TransparentProxyInterceptor is very slow. InterfaceInterceptor is recommended. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466(v=pandp.30).aspx#sec9

Answer (score 3):

The other way is:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.AddNewExtension<Interception>()
         .RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>()
         .Configure<Interception>()
         .SetInterceptorFor<IFoo>(new InterfaceInterceptor());
var foo = container.Resolve<IFoo>();
foo.Test();
```

And you create a class that inherits from HandlerAttribute and return an instance of type ICallHandler.Then add this attribute to the method to intercept.Something like this:

```
class MyAttribute : HandlerAttribute
{
   override ICallHandler CreateHandler(IUnityContainer container)
   {
       return new TestCallHandler();
   }
}


Interface IFoo
{
   [MyAttribute]
   void AMethod();
}
```